# Not understanding multiple test markers for test

Tags: python, pytest

I'm not understanding why I only get one suite of tests ran when I have multiple markers identified for each test and I'm calling each marker.

I've tried the following:

```
test_ac_il_rl_next.py

@pytest.fixture
# @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def setup_run_measurement(ssh_conn, get_marker_value):
    print("..Getting marker length" get_marker_value)
    # not sure how to get this particular active marker
    print("..Setting Switch")
    print("..AC/RF Test: running RF Sweep command")

@pytest.mark.ac_daily_30m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_100m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_200m
def test_setup(setup_run_measurement):
    assert True

@pytest.mark.ac_daily_30m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_100m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_200m
def test_il():
    print("AC/RF Test: IL ")


@pytest.mark.ac_daily_30m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_100m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_200m
def test_next():
    print("AC/RF Test: NEXT ")


@pytest.mark.ac_daily_30m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_100m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_200m
def test_rl():
    print("AC/RF Test: RL ")
```

When I run:
`python -m pytest -s -m "ac_daily_30m | ac_daily_100m"`

I only see the grouping / suite (setup, il, next, rl) tests ran once.  I was wanting this suite to run for each length (30m, 100m); twice.

This is what I see:

```
tests/rf/test_ac_il_rl_next.py ..Getting marker length ac_daily_30m | ac_daily_100m
..Setting up Daily Switch
..AC/RF Test: running RF Sweep command; measRfSe 2
.AC/RF Test: IL 
.AC/RF Test: NEXT 
.AC/RF Test: RL 
.
```

I'm setting up tests that have similar measurement / compare characteristics but will be setup differently based on length parameter. 
 Can this be done in one module `test_ac_il_rl_next.py`?  If so, how?  Or do I need to separate the modules with particular lengths (_30m.py, _100m.py, etc.)?  Or do I break up the tests with particular lengths (_30m, _100m, etc.).  If this can be ran in one module, is there a way to get the active marker that is running?

Comment: Custom markers do not parametrize tests. `pytest` offers a special marker for test parametrization, for example `@pytest.mark.parametrize('length', ['30m', '100m', '200m'])`. The marked test function then runs three times with different value of `length` parameter. You can of course define your own parametrization logic by processing the custom markers in custom hookimpl.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling.  Forgot to mention that doing the mark.paramatrize was also an option but decided that we prefer the option from command line to run single parameter instead of entire group.  I'll take a look at this custom hookimpl.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own parametrization scheme via custom impl of the [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests). Example:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'length' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        args = [m.name for m in metafunc.definition.iter_markers()
                if m.name.startswith('ac_daily_')]
        metafunc.parametrize('length', args)
```

Now a test

```
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_30m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_100m
@pytest.mark.ac_daily_200m
def test_il(length):
    print("AC/RF Test: IL ")
```

will be executed three times, once for each marker:

```
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_200m] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_100m] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_30m] PASSED
```

However, from

> When I run: `python -m pytest -s -m "ac_daily_30m | ac_daily_100m"`
>
> I only see the grouping / suite (setup, il, next, rl) tests ran once. I was wanting this suite to run for each length (30m, 100m); twice.

I assume you want also to redefine filtering by markers. By default `-m "ac_daily_30m | ac_daily_100m"` means *run any test that has marker* `ac_daily_30m` *or* `ac_daily_100m`; with the above hookimpl, it would execute `test_il` three times, with all three parameters - because each of three tests has the `ac_daily_30m` marker.

Hence, if you want to customize this behaviour, you will need some more tweaking to do. Example:

```
from _pytest.mark.legacy import MarkMapping


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    markexpr = metafunc.config.option.markexpr
    if 'length' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        args = [m.name for m in metafunc.definition.iter_markers()
                if eval(markexpr, {}, MarkMapping({m.name}))]
        metafunc.parametrize('length', args)
```

Running the above test with the new hookimpl:

```
$ pytest -m "ac_daily_100m"
...
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_100m] PASSED
...
```

Combining the markers via `or`:

```
$ pytest -m "ac_daily_30m | ac_daily_100m"
...
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_100m] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_il[ac_daily_30m] PASSED
...
```